# Issue using boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization, boost-unordered

Would you please help me with the issue below?  I've tried 3 days without success.

The problem is with my serialization code.  Whenever I try to instantiate the serialization, I encounter this error.

```
   Can't load '/home/scratch.bipham_ctg100/generic_dev/scripts/x86_64-linux/auto/nDB/nDB.so' for module nDB: /home/scratch.bipham_ctg100/generic_dev/scripts/x86_64-linux/auto/nDB/nDB.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost7archive17archive_exceptionE at ...
```

Below is the code I wrote

```
    //   nDB CONSTRUCTOR
    //**********************
    nDB::nDB() {
       //_LAYERS = new boost::unordered_map<string,layer,myhash,cmp_str>;
    }

    //   nDB DESTRUCTOR
    //**********************
    nDB::~nDB() {}

    //   nDB METHODS
    //**********************

    //===============================================================
    //  SERIALIZATION DEFINITION AND INITIALIZATION

    template<class Archive>
    void nDB::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
       boost::unordered_map<string,macro*,myhash,cmp_str>::const_iterator _ITER;
       for (_ITER = _MACROS.begin();_ITER != _MACROS.end();_ITER++) {
          ar & _ITER->first;
          ar & *(_ITER->second);
       }
    }
    //template void nDB::serialize<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>(
    // boost::archive::binary_oarchive & ar,
    // const unsigned int version
    //);
    //template void nDB::serialize<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>(
    // boost::archive::binary_iarchive & ar,
    // const unsigned int version
    //);
    //================================================================

    void nDB::save_macros(string filename) {
       std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
       boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
       oa << *this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link against the boost serialization library.  Try adding `-lboost_serialization` to your linker flags.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I did what you suggested and that error disappear but a different undefined symbol surface. It is now the symbol for boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer that is undefined. Would you please teach me how this linking process work?  I really appreciate your help.  I've spent 3 days on this and it is really frustrating.

Comment: @Binh: That's a big task.  I'd start with looking up linker, dynamic linker, and library(computing) on Wikipedia.  This should give you a good overview of what a linker does and why you need to link to the boost serialization library.  Your undefined symbol error indicates that the linker can't find that symbol in any of the object files or any of the libraries that it was told to include.  One possible cause of this could be that, if you have more than one version of the library installed, the linker could be linking to the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I really appreciate it.  I will do what you suggested.

Comment: Hi Sean, may I ask another question?  What does this message mean "-lboost_serialization: linker input file unused because linking not done"  Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi Binh, If I had to guess you added that option to the compiler flags and not the linker flags.  Compiling and linking are separate steps (although they can be combined).  You might want to read through your compiler manual.